# Can I create a RAID 1 array with a drive that already has data?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup, raid, disk-management

I am moving an IDE drive from a customer's old desktop into his new one. I want backup the old drive (drive 1) to a new drive (drive 2) before moving it to the new computer. Afterwards, I want to setup a RAID 1 array using both drives 1 and 2 so that there will be a backup when drive 1 eventually fails. I plan to use the Windows disk management utility rather than a physical array.

Is there a way to setup mirroring with a drive that already has data on it?

Comment: An answer has been provided with the how-to. But keep in mind that when you do this, if the first drive eventually fails, although the system will keep working, it will start to throw errors because the main startup partition is missing, and its now booting from a redundand drive. And in that state, it cannot be fixed easily. I've tested this extensively as a backup for my server, and when the mirror has both drives, it works great. But Windows will keep booting from the main drive even though its in a mirror.

Comment: Also, windows will see both drives when booting, giving a menu about selecting which of the two OS's you want to boot from even though they are identical. When the mirror fails and you add a new mirror, that boot menu will now have 3 OSses to select with one non-working one. So... you might want to consider using backup software and clone the disk rather than going for this make-shift situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a mirrored volume when data is already in the drive :

- Run Disk Management
- Right-click the primary drive with data on it and select "Add Mirror"
- Choose the drive that will be duplicate
- Click Add Mirror
- Click "Yes" to convert the basic disks to dynamic disks,
  which is a requirement for a mirrored volume

Windows will now synchronize the data on the primary drive with the
secondary drive, which can take a long time.

I would suggest to take another backup of the disk before starting,
just in case.

For detailed instructions with screenshots see the article
[How to set up a mirrored volume for file redundancy on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-mirrored-volume-file-redundancy-windows-10).

Comment: Although this is correct and also the only way if you want to keep the data, there should be a sidenote: Converting the disk to a dynamic disc cannot be reverted without completely wiping the disk, and backup software may not recognize this, nor might linux or mac. So you have to keep that in mind before committing to this.

Comment: Oh, also, you need to convert to a dynamic disk first. A drive that already has data on it, and is not empty, will have the add mirror option grayed out. Any mirror that you add that is not already a dynamic disk too will then get the question if you want to convert that disk to a dynamic disk also.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. This is actually definitely not recommended to do on the boot drive. Windows will see both mirrors as boot drives, and will give a boot menu at boot with 20 second time out. This can be altered of course, but Windows will keep booting from the primary drive. When that fails, windows will complain because it will keep attempting to boot from that failed drive regardless.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. The other answer will tell you how to do this. But I highly recommend against it, especially for a customer laptop that you will give back and not use yourself.

Once you change the boot partition to a dynamic disk and add a mirror, Windows will detect 2 boot partitions and create a startup menu to choose which partition to boot. The following screenshot is from a server 2016 install, but the situation is the same.

[image: Windows Server 2016 Dynamic Disk Boot manager]
**) This image is from Windows Server 2016, but applies to every version of Windows, including Windows 10.*

It will give a timeout of 20 seconds which can be annoying, but this can be altered luckily. The problem comes when that drive fails. Windows will still try to boot from it but fail. The user must select the other partition manually on every boot until they altered the boot manager startup sequence themselves. This is an advanced step. At least they can still boot, but it can be very annoying.

If you now try to add a new mirror to replace the old drive, a 3rd startup item is added to the menu.

Because of this, I recommend you to not do this, but instead clone the drive directly using backup software and only use one drive.

See also [https://zamarax.com/2020/10/19/how-to-...-windows-10-server-2016-server-2019/](https://zamarax.com/2020/10/19/how-to-mirror-raid1-boot-gpt-hard-drive-on-windows-10-server-2016-server-2019/)